# How to initialize struct

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-arrays

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to create and initialize a struct with values:

```
#define LINES 4
#define LENGHT 30

typedef struct
{
  char *name;
  char *phoneNumber;
  char *location;
  char *traveltype;
} Client;

void readClientData(char *filename, char *clientData[]);
Client *createClient(char *name, char *phoneNumber, char *location, char *traveltype);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *filename = argv[1];
  char *clientData = (char *)malloc(LINES * sizeof(char)*LENGHT);
  readClientData(filename, &clientData);
  Client *client = createClient(clientData[0], clientData[1], clientData[2], clientData[3]);
  return 0;
}

Client *createClient(char *name, char *phoneNumber, char *location, char *traveltype)
{
  Client *client = malloc(sizeof(Client));
  client->name = strdup(name);
  client->phoneNumber = strdup(phoneNumber);
  client->location = strdup(location);
  client->traveltype = strdup(traveltype);
  return client;
}
```

I'm trying to create my struct, but I get these errors:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
   Client *client = createClient(clientData[0], clientData[1], clientData[2], clientData[3]);

error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'Client*' [-fpermissive]
   Client *client = malloc(sizeof(Client));
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are compiling with c++ compiler, not with C. And except that, you are passing a `char` value, when your function expects a pointer to a valid string. No idea what you want to do there anyway and why do you pass those data.

Comment: `clientData[0]` is not a pointer to a character array. Did you mean `&clientData[0]`? What does `readClientData` do?

Comment: Oh, my mistake, thanks for pointing it out, it is a bit late. I've wanted a `char *clientData[]` as an array of strings.

Comment: @LegendofPedro readClientData reads lines from a file and adds every line to the clientData array. The problem is that I've made an array of chars, not an array of char pointers I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `clientData` is a `char *`, `clientData[i]` is a simple character. This conflicts with `createClient ()` prototype which expects pointers to chars, that are NULL terminated strings.

Please note that after mallocing them you never initialize them. That would be a problem at run time, since `strdup ()` requires something to copy (at least an empty string!).

The second error requires you to cast the result of malloc to `Client *` (even here in SO many might tell you to avoid it, many compilers require it).

Comment: Oh, I've wanted to create a dynamic array of strings. So I reckon I should have written `char *clientData[]` am I right? Also thanks for the response :)

Comment: Better. But you will have to revise the initial malloc too: every char* of the array will have to be malloced separately. And you still need to initialize every string (copying data from some input source, maybe).

Comment: `void *` (which is the return type of `malloc`) is automatically translated into any pointer type; `C++` compilers require it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Type_safety

Answer (score 1):

The read and create operations could be combined. Then as the file is read, the number of Clients can be increased using `realloc`. Allocate one additional structure to act as a sentinel. Or keep track of the number of structures allocated.
For each structure, try to read four lines from the file and `strdup` the line to the structure pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    char *phoneNumber;
    char *location;
    char *traveltype;
} Client;

char *linefree ( char *line) {
    free ( line);
    return NULL;
}

Client *clientfree ( Client *client) {
    size_t count = 0;
    //the sentinel element will have name as NULL
    while ( client && client[count].name) {
        client[count].name = linefree ( client[count].name);
        client[count].phoneNumber = linefree ( client[count].phoneNumber);
        client[count].location = linefree ( client[count].location);
        client[count].traveltype = linefree ( client[count].traveltype);
        count++;
    }
    free ( client);
    return NULL;
}

void showclient ( Client *client) {
    size_t count = 0;
    //the sentinel element will have name as NULL
    while ( client && client[count].name) {
        printf ( "%s\n", client[count].name);
        if ( client[count].phoneNumber) {
            printf ( "   %s\n", client[count].phoneNumber);
        }
        if ( client[count].location) {
            printf ( "   %s\n", client[count].location);
        }
        if ( client[count].traveltype) {
            printf ( "   %s\n", client[count].traveltype);
        }
        count++;
    }
}

Client *readClientData ( char *filename) {
    size_t count = 0;
    FILE *pf = NULL;
    Client *client = NULL;
    Client *temp = NULL;
    if ( NULL == ( pf = fopen ( filename, "r"))) {
        perror ( filename);
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ( 1) {
        // count + 2 to have sentinel element
        if ( NULL == ( temp = realloc ( client, sizeof *client * ( count + 2)))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "realloc problem\n");
            return client;
        }
        client = temp;
        //set current element to NULL
        client[count].name = NULL;
        client[count].phoneNumber = NULL;
        client[count].location = NULL;
        client[count].traveltype = NULL;
        count++;
        //following serves as sentinel element
        client[count].name = NULL;
        client[count].phoneNumber = NULL;
        client[count].location = NULL;
        client[count].traveltype = NULL;

        char line[1024] = "";

        if ( ! fgets ( line, sizeof line, pf)) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            break;
        }
        if ( NULL == ( client[count - 1].name = strdup ( line))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "strdup name problem\n");
            break;
        }
        if ( ! fgets ( line, sizeof line, pf)) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            break;
        }
        if ( NULL == ( client[count - 1].phoneNumber = strdup ( line))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "strdup phoneNumber problem\n");
            break;
        }
        if ( ! fgets ( line, sizeof line, pf)) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            break;
        }
        if ( NULL == ( client[count - 1].location = strdup ( line))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "strdup location problem\n");
            break;
        }
        if ( ! fgets ( line, sizeof line, pf)) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            break;
        }
        if ( NULL == ( client[count - 1].traveltype = strdup ( line))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "strdup traveltype problem\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose ( pf);
    return client;
}

int main ( void) {
    char filename[1024] = "";
    printf ( "Enter a filename\n");
    if ( ! fgets ( filename, sizeof filename, stdin)) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "fgetline filename problem\n");
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    filename[strcspn ( filename, "\n")] = 0;//remove trailing newline
    Client *client = readClientData ( filename);

    showclient ( client);

    client = clientfree ( client);

    return 0;
}
```